# Proof of the existence of a special parametrization of the trefoil knot.

Tags: knot-theory

Could someone kindly exhibit a periodic $ C^{2} $-function $ f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ with period $ 1 $ such that
$$
\{ (f(x),f'(x),f''(x)) \,|\, x \in [0,1] \}
$$
represents a trefoil knot in $ \mathbb{R}^{3} $?